# Simple question about computation of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ and $F$ two smooth curves with genus $g>2$. Defines $S=E \times F $ the cartesian product of the two curves. So, by definition,  S is a complex algebraic surface.
Let $p$ the projection of $S$ on $E$ and $q$ the projection of $S$ on F. If $K_E$ is the canonical divisor on the curve $E$, how can i write the divisor $p^{*}K_E$ where the * means the pull-back?

Comment: In what sense (that is, how explicitly) do you want to write this divisor? If $K_E=\sum_r p_r$ (with repetitions allowed), then $p^*K_E=\sum_r \{p_r\}\times F$.

Comment: i've found that $p^{*}(K_E)=(2g(E)-2)F$. Is it true?

Comment: (JUST TO BE CLEAR) if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a holomorfic function between complex algebraic variety,  how the divisor $f^{*}(D)$ is defined where $D \in Div(Y)$?

Comment: i know the definition when $X,Y$ are riemann surface.